# error method range of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have read just about every question regarding the error and have not found the solution yet. I am trying to copy a range of data based on concatenated criteria from sheet 1 to sheet 2. The code seems to be working up until the match is found and it time to extract the data, the I get the error. code below. The first match from M to S is on the fifth row. the code loops until the fifth iteration then errors on the copy section right after THEN

```
Public Sub myWay()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim rngs As range
Dim rngm As range



Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

Set rngs = wsSource.range("L2")
Set rngm = wsMain.range("L2")





    'Clear old data
    wsMain.range("D2:L1500").ClearContents
    wsSource.range("L2:L1500").ClearContents


    wsMain.range("L2:L" & range("A65000").End(xlUp).row).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-11],RC[-10],RC[-9])"
    wsSource.range("L2:L" & range("A65000").End(xlUp).row).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-11],RC[-10],RC[-9])"




        Do Until rngm.Value <> "" And rngm.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
            Do Until rngs.Value <> "" And rngs.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
                If (rngs.Value = rngm.Value) Then

                    wsMain.range("D" & rngm.row & "J" & rngm.row).Value = _
                    wsSource.range("D" & rngs.row & "J" & rngs.row).Value

                 End If
                 Set rngs = rngs.Offset(1, 0)

              Loop
              Set rngm = rngm.Offset(1, 0)

          Loop



End Sub
```

I have tried using the sheet name and several other tweaks but I am out of ideas. any help understanding the error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a colon (`:`) before "J":

```
wsMain.range("D" & rngm.row & ":J" & rngm.row).Value = _
wsSource.range("D" & rngs.row & ":J" & rngs.row).Value
```

Comment: I knew it was something so small. that did the trick. but I think I am missing one more bit. After it finds the match and copies the values, it continues looking through the source instead of looping to the next line in main. I really appreciate any advice, I've been taking online courses and trying to figure this out for  a while but I just seem to keep getting hung up on some items that I'm not getting out of the courses.

Comment: So I changed the first do line to Do Until rngm.Value = rngs.Value Or rngm.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
            Do Until rngs.Value = rngm.Value Or rngs.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
                If (rngs.Value = rngm.Value) Then. So when I walk through I can see the loop is behaving correctly but the copy is not happening.

Comment: Try to control all your values of interest: rows and values you copy. Assign variables to `rngm.row` and `rngs.row` and check the ranges. Then assign a variable to `wsSource.range("D" & rngs.row & ":J" & rngs.row).Value`  and see what it brings. I believe there is something in a wrong referencing of cells.